# Speed up image filter in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, filter, pixel

I wrote an image filter in C++. It takes each pixel of a 32bpp bitmap with 256 rows (storing pixels in a row by row contiguous array), performs an operation with it's neighboring pixels within a 5x5 region, and produces 4 output pixels to make an image 2x the resolution of the original image. This is all being done on the CPU.

The filter doesn't run as fast as I'd like. I need it to run below 16 milliseconds consistently. Could I speed it up with multithreading, or would the overhead be inconsistent and possible take longer than 16 ms in total? Is there any other method that could speed it up?

If multithreading could speed it up, the more specific the implementation the better. Any code examples would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think multi threading would be hard because the pixels all rely on each other for the final output. I did something similar to this once where I calculated if a certain pixels neighbor values were below a certain threshold the change wouldn't be noticeable so ignore them until the pixels near it would have changed more. I do not know if this would work for your specific situation though.

Comment: @Ellery, `I think multi threading would be hard because the pixels all rely on each other for the final output`, I believe, that pixels rely on unmodified neighboring pixels.

Comment: I should have mentioned, the input pixels are never modified, and each output pixel is modified once, however since each input pixel reads its neighbors each input pixel is read multiple times.

Comment: Why do you need it under 16ms? If it is because your program is processing a continuous stream of frames and you want to achieve 60 frames/second, it may be better to determine how many cores you have up front and then send an entire frame to each core rather than subdivide each frame amongst your available cores. It could also be highly dependent on your CPU cache size.

Comment: It might be a good idea to post the core of your processing code that implements the filter as there may be some improvements to be made there...

Comment: Which processor, language and compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your problem is "trivially parallel", so Multithreading could definitely help with a near-linear improvement.. This is a classic data subdivision problem. You can subdivide your image into N regions ( N = # of threads you want ). Each region will need something like (Dimension/N+4) Pixels of the image (each region will have a few pixels of overlap, "Ghost Cells", to accomodate the 5x5 kernel you're applying).  Then all the threads write into particular regions of a common "output" region.  Since the threads don't overlap their output zones, you don't need any Mutex or locking.

For example, if you have a 256x256 image and you use 4 threads:

- Each thread gets a strip of (256 / 4 + 4) = 68 pixels.. Their own unique 64-pixel region and 2 extra pixels on each side.  They compute on the 64-pixel region in the center (the outside pixels are just for the 5x5 convolution kernel)
- Or, each thread gets a 132x132 block (128x128 + 4 on each side), and does the same.

This is a classic MPI subdivision technique, but easily accomplished in lots of other libraries as well.

Comment: I'm not sure it will work. For instance, Gaussian Blur is usually Memory Bounded (If written in SSE) so unless he carefully tile the image processing, it won't generate speed up.

Answer (score 0):

The task at hand is clearly highly parallelizable - meaning **multi-threading will help**. The general idea is:

1. Allocate (contiguous) memory for the target image, consider proper pitch/padding(if necessary)
2. Figure out how many CPUs you have available
3. Split the image area into `n` regions - either rows, columns, or rectangular areas
4. Spawn `n` parallel worker threads, each one picking up a chunk of work
5. It will definitely help if you set affinity masks for those threads so they execute on the same core every time they are active

Comment: What is affinity mask? What about keeping it below memory band width bound?

Comment: An affinity mask specifies which CPU core to allocate for which threat, in other words it guarantees that a threat will not jump from CPU core to CPU core (thus the "affinity"). Memory bandwidth is something you can't really depend on as it is affected by factors like motherboard physical architecture/layout, memory controller's performance, cache characteristics - all of which are beyond the reach of software application's access (and for a good reason, too).